# make a shape appear and disappear on click

Tags: excel, vba

what i want to do is the following:
if i click on an object in excel it should create a bubble shape. When i click the SAME object again the created bubble should disapper.

```
Option Explicit

Public Shp As Shape

Sub Bubble2()

' set object reference to new created Shape
Set Shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeCloudCallout, 795, 8.25, 107.25, 41.25)

With Shp
    .Name = "zooky"
    .Adjustments.Item(1) = -0.25029
    .TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "text.................."
End With

With Shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 10)
    With .ParagraphFormat
        .FirstLineIndent = 0
        .Alignment = msoAlignLeft
    End With
    With .Font
        .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
        .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
        .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        .Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorLight1
        .Fill.ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .Fill.ForeColor.Brightness = 0
        .Fill.Transparency = 0
        .Fill.Solid
        .Size = 11
        .Name = "+mn-lt"
    End With
End With

Range("P5").Select

' just for testing
'Call FlipFlop2

End Sub

Sub FlipFlop2()
    With Shp
        .Visible = Not .Visible
    End With
End Sub
```

if i assign the flipflop macro to the clickable object it gives me an error that there is no object (because the bubble was not created yet and he wants to trigger fliflop) so what i have to do now is assign the bubble macro to one object and the flipflop macro to another object so i can create the bubble at on object and to hide it i need to click on another spot. What i need now is that my sub works like this: (assign flipflop macro to object)->click obj-> check if the bubble is there->if not create one 1st(trigger bubble)->if its there hide it.

i hope you get what i mean...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Bubble2()

    Dim shp As Shape

    On Error Resume Next
    Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes("zooky")
    On Error GoTo 0

    If shp Is Nothing Then
        'doesn't yet exist: create
        ' set object reference to new created Shape
        Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeCloudCallout, 795, 8.25, 107.25, 41.25)

        With shp
            .Name = "zooky"
            .Adjustments.Item(1) = -0.25029
            .TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "text.................."
        End With

        With shp.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 10)
            With .ParagraphFormat
                .FirstLineIndent = 0
                .Alignment = msoAlignLeft
            End With
            With .Font
                .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
                .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
                .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
                .Fill.ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorLight1
                .Fill.ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
                .Fill.ForeColor.Brightness = 0
                .Fill.Transparency = 0
                .Fill.Solid
                .Size = 11
                .Name = "+mn-lt"
            End With
        End With
    Else
        'already exists: toggle vis
        shp.Visible = Not shp.Visible
    End If

    Range("P5").Select

End Sub
```